# Assign output to variable in Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to assign the output of cURL into a variable like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
$IP=`curl automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp`
echo $IP
sed s/IP/$IP/ nsupdate.txt | nsupdate
```

However, when I run the script the following happens:

> ```
> ./update.sh: 3: =[my ip address]: not found
> ```

How can I get the output into `$IP` correctly?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but there's another minor distinction between that example and what's here: if the $IP var passed to echo is not wrapped in double quotes, it will only output the last line of the captured curl output.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherHunter, I came here just looking for this. Why does it behave this way though?

Comment: @Amey I can't say exactly what the reasoning was, just that this is how echo behaves when you give it a multi-line string as an argument.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

In shell, you don't put a $ in front of a variable you're assigning.  You only use $IP when you're referring to the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(curl automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp)

echo "$IP"

sed "s/IP/$IP/" nsupdate.txt | nsupdate
```

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the output and progress bar of `curl`? Adding `-silent` leaves `$IP` empty...

Comment: @Dror, `curl` sends its noisy output to stderr, so the progress bar should be ignored in the case of a script like this.  Nevertheless, `--silent` or `-s` works just fine.  If you have troubles, please [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Use `curl -s` to disable the progress bar and error messages.

Comment: You can always redirect `stderr`: `IP=$(curl <url> 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: finding with the $() syntax i'm not able to use env variables e.g. instead of hard coding an email I want to use $2, $3 as variables. Any ideas on why these wont render?

Comment: @EvanBurbidge .. it's not entirely clear what you're asking. Perhaps you could [make a question of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and show a reproducible example of what isn't working for you?

Comment: My apologies I was trying to use bash variables instead of hard coding my strings it turns out I had to stop the main string wrapped in the -d '{}' in order to do this ``` AUTH=$(curl -X POST -d '{ "email": "'"$TRANSLATION_EMAIL"'", "password": "'"$TRANSLATION_PASS"'" }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" $LOGIN_URL)```

Answer (score 41):

Same with something more complex...getting the ec2 instance region from within the instance.

```
INSTANCE_REGION=$(curl -s 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document' | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['region']")

echo $INSTANCE_REGION
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was doing in my bash script and you saved me from having to apt-get install jq!

Comment: How can this be done on windows? if I substitute the `$` with `os.system`, INSTANCE_REGION does not have the value of the output.

Comment: How to make that multi-line?

Comment: @KhalilGharbaoui just use \ in the end of the line