# sed: remove whole words containg a character class

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, awk, sed

I'd like to remove any word which contains a non alpha char from  a text file. e.g

```
"ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5"
```

should become

```
"ok"
```

I've tried using

```
echo "ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5" | sed 's/\b[a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z]\+[a-zA-Z]*\b/ /g'
```

Comment: Is it non-alpha you want removing, or is it numeric? What was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: All non-alpha, not just numeric. It produced a wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
s="ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5"
awk '{ofs=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
         {printf "%s%s", ofs, $i; ofs=OFS} print ""}' <<< "$s"
ok
```

This `awk` command loops through all words and if word matches the regex `/^[[:alpha:]]+$/` then it writes to standard out. `(i<NF)?OFS:RS` is a short cut to add `OFS` if current field no is less than `NF` otherwise it writes `RS`.

Using `grep` + `tr` together:

```
s="ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5"
r=$(grep -o '[^ ]\+' <<< "$s"|grep '^[[:alpha:]]\+$'|tr '\n' ' ')
echo "$r"
ok
```

First `grep -o` breaks the string into individual words. 2nd grep only searches for words with alphabets only. ANd finally `tr` translates `\n` to space.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add an explanation?

Comment: I was told by someone that I always needed parentheses to be portable when testing in `printf`. I do see you do `(i<NF)?OFS:RS`.  Is this better or worse than `(i<NF?OFS:RS)`?

Comment: @Dimid: I added explanation to my answer.

Comment: I repeat my comment written below: please use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of the buggy `[a-zA-Z]`, because if you replace in `s` your "ok" by "Öcalan", for instance, your script outputs an empty string. :(

Comment: @Jotne - in some awks (e.g. OSX awk) `print <ternary>` will cause a syntax error depending on the condition in the ternary expression while `print (<ternary>)` will always succeed. I don't know for sure if there are other situations in which an unparenthesized ternary expression will fail, nor do I know if just parenthesizing the condition part of the expression is enough to get around that. I personally find parenthesizing the whole expressions easier to read anyway and I know it works in all situations so I just do that.

Comment: I actually work on OSX and tested above awk using default OSX version of awk. But yes for better compatibility it seems it will be better to use `(i<NF?OFS:RS)`

Comment: @anubhava +1 for the solution but you need to change your `printf` because if the last field on the line contains a non-alpha character then you won't get a newline at the end of the line and depending on the preceding fields contents you may have a hanging blank char too.

Comment: Thanks Ed. But if you notice in the input string last field already has a non-alpha character above.

Comment: Yes it does and as I mentioned your solution is adding a trailing blank char and not providing a newline. You need `awk '{ofs=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/) {printf "%s%s", ofs, $i; ofs=OFS} print "" }'` or similar.

Comment: Yes that's right, I also notice trailing space issue. Let me put up an edited version.

Comment: IMHO adding it and then removing it as a much worse approach than just not adding it in the first place.

Comment: Yes I could have stored those fields in an array and print in later but that is definitely more code than this code. And come to think of it, it is just removing a single space from end of string.

Comment: Did you see the suggestion I put i my comment? It just prints the space before each field except the first one rather than after each field and it's briefer and IMHO clearer than what you currently have.

Comment: Ah I totally missed it. Sorry let me just edit the answer using your nice suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The following **sed** command does the job:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]*[^[:space:][:alpha:]][^[:space:]]*//g'
```

It removes all words containing at least one non-alphabetic character. It is better to use POSIX character classes like `[:alpha:]`, because for instance they won't consider the French name "François" as being faulty (i.e. containing a non-alphabetic character).

#### Explanation

We remove all patterns starting with an arbitrary number of spaces followed by an arbitrary (possibly nil) number of alphabetic characters, followed by at least one non-space and non-alphabetic character, and then glob to the end of the word (i.e. until the next space). Please note that you may want to swap `[:space:]` for `[:blank:]`, see [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for a detailed explanation of the difference between these two POSIX classes.

#### Test

```
$ echo "ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5" | sed 's/[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]*[^[:space:][:alpha:]][^[:space:]]*//g'
ok
```

Comment: +1, I was trying to work out something along these lines myself. Your command in perl: `perl -pe 's/\s*[[:alpha:]]*[^\s[:alpha:]]\S*//g'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about losing different numbers of spaces between each word, you could use something like this in Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print join(" ", grep { !/[^[:alpha:]]/ } @F), "\n"
```

the `-a` switch enables auto-split mode, which splits the text on any number of spaces and stores the fields in the array `@F`. `grep` filters out the elements of that array that contain any non-alphabetical characters. The resulting array is joined on a single space.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\b([[:alpha:]]+\b ?)|\S+\b ?/\1/g;s/ $//' file
```

This uses a back reference within alternation to save the required string.

Answer (score -1):

```
 st="ok 0bad ba1d bad3 4bad4 5bad5bad5"
 for word in $st; 
     do 
     if [[ $word =~  ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; 
         then 
             echo $word; 
      fi; 
 done
```

Comment: That's not how you assign variables in bash.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8737671/1072112).

Comment: by mistake i added $ and space