# How to capture the output of curl to variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl

So, lets say I have the following command:

```
curl -I http://google.com | head -n 1| cut -d $' ' -f2
```

This will capture the http status code??
Now I want to assign this to variable.. in bash script

```
like output = "curl -I http://localhost:8088/tracks?key=9 | head -n 1| cut -d $' ' -f2"
```

or something like that..

How do I assign the response of above command to a variable called output in bash?
Thanks

Comment: try surrounding the command in back ticks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have two options (see this StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737638/assign-curl-output-to-variable-in-bash?rq=1)):

- **Preferred:** Surround the invocation in `$()`
- Surround the invocation in back ticks

> NOTE: [back ticks are legacy](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006), the former method is preferred.

```sh
output=$(curl -I http://google.com | head -n 1| cut -d $' ' -f2)
echo "$output";

output=`curl -I http://google.com | head -n 1| cut -d $' ' -f2`
echo "$output";
```