# I'm getting errors in my shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

MY CODE :

```
echo "Please Enter The Purchase Price : "
read $PurPrice
echo "Please Enter The Selling Price : "
read $SellPrice

if [ "$PurPrice" -eq "$SellPrice" ]
        then
                echo "No Profit No Loss !"

elif [ "$PurPrice" -gt "$SellPrice" ]
        then
                loss=echo "$pp - $sp" | bc -l
                echo "There is loss of $loss."
else
        profit=echo "$sp - $pp" | bc -l
        echo "There is Profit $profit. "
fi
```

THE ERRORS :

```
Please Enter The Purchase Price :                                                                                                 
': not a valid identifier `                                                                                                       
Please Enter The Selling Price :                                                                                                  
': not a valid identifier `                                                                                                         
    Newfile.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found                                                                                      
    Newfile.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'                                                                    
    'ewfile.sh: line 10: elif [ "$PurPrice" -gt "$SellPrice" ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least, the same problem as) [Assign curl output to variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737638/assign-curl-output-to-variable-in-bash)

Comment: Also not sure what this has to do with the vi editor...

Comment: DOS line-endings are a problem but so is using `$` in the `read` commands.

Comment: On both of your "read" lines, you do not need the "$" symbol. "$" is used when you want the value of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has lots of issues.

- You were not consistent in your variable names (e.g. pp vs. PurPrice)
- You only use $ when you want the value of a variable (not on read's
  for example).
- You can't use strings with the integer test operators (-eq and so on).
- You need backticks to get the output of commands you run.

Here is functional code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please Enter The Purchase Price : "
read PurPrice

echo "Please Enter The Selling Price : "
read SellPrice

if [ $PurPrice -eq $SellPrice ] ; then
        echo "No Profit No Loss !"
elif [ $PurPrice -gt $SellPrice ] ; then
        loss=`echo "$PurPrice - $SellPrice" | bc -l`
        echo "There is loss of $loss."
else
        profit=`echo "$SellPrice - $PurPrice" | bc -l`
        echo "There is Profit $profit. "
fi
```

but note that the test operators (-eq -gt etc) only work on integers (entering a price like 1.99 will cause it to fail)!

Comment: Here's a fun solution to the "only works on integers" problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33759747/1072112

Comment: Quoting the variables in `test`/`[` contexts is important.

Comment: How to get the floating Value ??